# Prevent scrolling inside two level child elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following structure:

```
<div id="parent">
content 1
<div id="child1">
content2
<div id="child2">
content 3
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

For all 3 elements I am using overflow-y: scroll and -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; and each one has a specific height for the content to be overflown inside of it.

The reason I need this is mainly for mobile use. What I need to be done is for the parent element of each of the contents, NOT to scroll when it reaches its bottom end. The usual behaviour is, when the child 2 element scrolls down to its bottom, child 1 starts scrolling and when it reaches down, parent starts scrolling. I have used a couple of scripts but none of them seem to be working properly.

I would like this for both mobile and desktop use. I know it has to do something with preventing mouse wheel, key and touch actions, but have no idea how to implement it.

I've been banging my head for like a week with no results. Any help will be appreciated greatly!

Comment: I can't guarantee it to work in your case, but I've written a script for basic usage to prevent behavior you're describing. Check: http://www.hakoniemi.net/labs/nonbounce/ . But like mentioned, this is very experimental (v0.1) and may cause interference with other scrolling behavior

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this is not what I am trying to avoid. What I am looking for is for a way that when you are scrolling over an element (either mouse or touch) have all of its parent elements STOP scrolling. So, when you are scrolling inside child2, scrolling should be disabled for both child 1, and parent (and its parents if any) and so on..